How to obtain the coroots of $\operatorname{SL}_2$?
Let $G = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and fix the maximal torus $T$ being the diagonal matrices in $G$. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \operatorname{Lie}(G)$, $\mathfrak{h} = \operatorname{Lie}(T)$ as usual, and consider the adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ by conjugation. One has a root space decomposition
$$\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in X^*(T)} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$$
where $X^*(T) = \operatorname{Hom}(T, \mathbb{C}^\times)$ is the character lattice and
$$\mathfrak{g}_\alpha = \{x \in \mathfrak{g} : txt^{-1} = \alpha(t)x \;\forall\; t \in T\}$$
We call $\alpha$ a root if $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha \neq 0$. A coroot of $\alpha \in X^*(T)$ is an element $\alpha^\vee \in X_*(T) = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{C}^\times, T)$ such that $\alpha \circ \alpha^\vee: \mathbb{C}^\times \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ gives the map $t \mapsto t^2$.
One can show, by direct computation, that the roots of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ are the maps
$$\alpha_{\pm}: \begin{bmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & t^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \mapsto t^{\pm 2}$$
and it follows that (for example) the coroots $\alpha_{+}^\vee$ are of the form
$$t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & t^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{or} \quad t \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} -t & 0 \\ 0 & -t^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$$
But I am not sure which one is actually the coroot of $\alpha_+$. Is there some extra requirement for a coroot other than $\alpha \circ \alpha^\vee = (t \mapsto t^2)$?
Note: I am trying to tackle this from the algebraic group perspective, and so as you can see, I am not using the standard notion from root system of Lie algebras.
Another thing I am not sure is how does one define an inner product on $X_*(T)$? In Lie algebra, we have the Killing form $(-,-): \mathfrak{h} \times \mathfrak{h} \to \mathbb{C}$ and then one can define the coroot of $\alpha \in \Delta \subset \mathfrak{h}^*$ as $\alpha^\vee = 2 \alpha / (H_\alpha, H_\alpha)$, where $H_\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}$ is the unique element satisfying $\alpha = (H_\alpha, -)$. Is there some kind of dictionary that allows us to translate this to the setting with $X^*(T)$ and $X_*(T)$?
